# AngularJs - Select checkboxes by binding list of selected objects to list of all objects

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I have searched for a solution to my problem but have not been able to find the right answer.
I have a list of *all* questions and a list of *selected* questions. I need to build a list of checkboxes from the list of all questions and check the ones that are in the list of selected questions.  When changes are made to the checkboxes, I need the list of selected questions to be updated accordingly.  The list of all questions never changes.  How can I accomplish this?  Here's a very abbreviated version of my situation:

```js
        var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

        MyApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

            $scope.allQuestions = [
                { q_id: 1, q_txt: 'What time is it?', q_sort: 1},
                { q_id: 2, q_txt: 'What is that?', q_sort: 2},
                { q_id: 3, q_txt: 'Who are you?', q_sort: 4},
                { q_id: 4, q_txt: 'What color is that?', q_sort: 3}
            ];

            $scope.selectedQuestions = [
                { q_id: 1, other_prop: 'yyy' },
                { q_id: 4, other_prop: 'zzz' },
            ];
        }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">

        <div ng-repeat="question in allQuestions"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="x" /> {{ question.q_txt }}</div>

    </div>
```

In my application the lists come from a server and I would like to be able to return the selected questions list as an object back to the server when saving the changes.
I can't figure out the binding to accomplish this, or how to check the right checkboxes.  Notice that the two lists are different, but bothe have the q_id value as the key to match them.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you need to worry about which questions are selected until the user submits the form, so I'd just loop through the list of all questions at that time and create an array of the selected questions.

Something like this:

```
function getSelections() {
    var selectedQuestions = []
    $scope.allQuestions.forEach( function(question) {
        if (question.selected) {
            var questionCopy = angular.copy(question)
            selectedQuestions.push(questionCopy)
        }
    })
    return selectedQuestions
}
```

Then call this function before you post and pass the results to your API.

You should just be able to use ng-model to handle preselecting the checkboxes that should be preselected with:

```
<div ng-repeat="question in allQuestions"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="question.selected" /> {{ question.q_txt }}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike.  You are correct, the submitting part is the easy part.  My main concern is how to pre-select the checkboxes for the questions that come selected from the database.

Comment: I made an edit to the code. I had added the "selected" property while testing and forgot to remove it before posting it. The list of all questions will not have that property, as it is a list of all questions available in the system. The list of selectedQuestions represent what is selected. Sorry.

Comment: So you are receiving 2 lists from the API, one that's a list of all questions and one that's a list of just the selected questions?

Comment: That is correct.  These questions are part of a larger object so the larger object gives me the list of questions selected for it and I need to check the corresponding questions in the list of ALL questions available.

Comment: I added a new answer. Too much irrelevant discussion here to flush out what you're after. I'll delete my original answer after this gets sorted out

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick. Using array.find() might be more efficient. Using a library like _ would make this easier.

```
   $scope.selectedQuestions.map( function(selectedQuestion) {
        var match = $scope.allQuestions.some( function(question) {
             if (question.q_id == selectedQuestion.q_id) {
                 question.selected = true
                 return true 
             }
             return false
        }
    }
```